# Oracle database encoding problems

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, nls-lang

We have two Oracle databases. We read data from database1 in database2 through dblink.
In database1 we have `NLS_CHARACTERSET = AL32UTF8` and in database2 `NLS_CHARACTERSET = EE8ISO8859P2`.

The problem is that reading data in database2 it's wrong. Some special characters are wrong. For example:

Data in database1: ÎNTREPRINDERE INDIVIDUALĂ

Data in database2: ?NTREPRINDERE INDIVIDUAL?

Can someone explain why (bytes representation ) and what are the solutions (are more than the one to modify nls_characterset)?

Comment: You cannot just change a database's `nls_characterset`. Ask your DBAs to create a new `al32utf8` database for you and migrate the data there. If not possible, you may try typecasting the data being queried to `nvarchar2`. As to "why" this happens - I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typecasting I suggested in my comment seems to work (for me).

**Demo**

I have an `AL32UTF8` remote DB and an `EE8MSWIN1250` local DB to my avail, so I had to use something different than Romanian as those chars are present in the cp1250 codepage. Went for some Russian, then.

*At remote DB...*

```
create table test_the_charset (xxx varchar2(256 char));

insert into test_the_charset (xxx)
values (n'ÎNTREPRINDERE INDIVIDUALĂ');

insert into test_the_charset (xxx)
values (n'Сегодня замечательный день, чтобы помочь людям на StackOverflow.com.');

commit;
```

*At local DB...*

```
SQL> select xxx from test_the_charset@my_remote_db;

XXX
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ÎNTREPRINDERE INDIVIDUALĂ
??????? ????????????? ????, ????? ?????? ????? ?? StackOverflow.com.

SQL> select cast(xxx as nvarchar2(2000)) from test_the_charset@my_remote_db;

CAST(XXXASNVARCHAR2(2000))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ÎNTREPRINDERE INDIVIDUALĂ
Сегодня замечательный день, чтобы помочь людям на StackOverflow.com.

SQL>
```

**As for "why this happens"...**

I don't know. ISO8859-2 should, by definition, allow for storing Romanian characters, hence they should get transferred via DB link without problems. Yet, in your case, they don't.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Do you know the reason. I don't understand why we should do this cast.

Comment: @F.Lazarescu, unfortunately, I don't. (Answer updated.)